# Webpack 5 Module Federation throwing error Module doesn't exists in the container

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, single-spa

I am trying to build a remote/host sample MFE using Single SPA with Module Federation feature from WebPack 5.

but I am getting this error in the host application

[image]

here is the webpack of the remote:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3001/",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3001,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "mfe",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {},
      exposes: {
        "/EventListing":"./src/Events/EventListing",
      },
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

and this is WebPack of the host

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");

const deps = require("./package.json").dependencies;
module.exports = {
  output: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/",
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".jsx", ".js", ".json"],
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: "javascript/auto",
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|s[ac]ss)$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: "host",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      remotes: {
        "mfe":"mfe@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js"
      },
      exposes: {},
      shared: {
        ...deps,
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        "react-dom": {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps["react-dom"],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

and here is the index.tsx of the host app:

```
import { registerApplication, start } from 'single-spa';
import './index.d';
registerApplication(
  'event-listing',
  () => import('mfe/EventListing'),
  location => location.pathname.startsWith('/')
);

start();
```

and finally here is the HTML of the host app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>host</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="single-spa-application:event-listing"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell webpack exactly which file you are wanting to serve -- change `"/EventListing":"./src/Events/EventListing"` to `"/EventListing":"./src/Events/EventListing.js"`

Answer (score 2):

The error show it ('./EventListing'), maybe you should change:

```
exposes: {
  "/EventListing":"./src/Events/EventListing",
}
```

to

```
exposes: {
  "./EventListing":"./src/Events/EventListing",
}
```